# How to get the Amazon account email info in AWS lambda

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda

I am using a lambda function in Amazon. Is there a way to get the email id linked to the AWS account from python code in lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

The [`describe-organization`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/describe-organization.html?highlight=root) command in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) returns this information:

```
aws organizations describe-organization
```

Output:

```
{
  "Organization": {
    "MasterAccountArn": "arn:aws:organizations::111111111111:account/o-exampleorgid/111111111111",
    "MasterAccountEmail": "bill@example.com",
    "MasterAccountId": "111111111111",
    "Id": "o-exampleorgid",
    "FeatureSet": "ALL",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:organizations::111111111111:organization/o-exampleorgid",
    "AvailablePolicyTypes": [
      {
        "Status": "ENABLED",
        "Type": "SERVICE_CONTROL_POLICY"
    ]
  }
}
```

**AWS Organizations** was [introduced in early 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/category/aws-organizations/) as a means of managing multiple AWS Accounts in a hierarchy.

See: [AWS Organizations Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/organizations/)